# Effect of short lived chemicals on global warming exceeding effect of carbon dioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, catalysis, environmental-chemistry, atmospheric-chemistry

From [Wikipedia:  Global Warming Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_warming_potential)

> #### GWP values and lifetimes:
>
> Nitrous oxide lasts about 121 years in the atmosphere, causes about 280 times as much warming over 20 years, but about 300 times as much over 100 years.
>
> HFC-23 lasts about 222 years, causes about 11,400 times the warming over twenty years, but about 13,600 times over one hundred years.

Carbon dioxide is widely believed to last at least 300 years, if not longer, in the atmosphere.

How can certain short-lived chemicals cause more global warming in the long term, relative to carbon dioxide, than they do in the short term?

Comment: CO2 is ~constant in the atmosphere (yes, increasing but…). Now release a burst of something that decays away - what is the impact of it over time?

Comment: Note that estimated halftime of atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ is dozens of years. It is not that obvious, as it is constantly supplied by natural and human-triggered processes, so its level is a steady state with long term drift. So it should not be surprise those components are evern more effective in long-term, beincg compared to $\ce{CO2.}$